# How to get latest valid partition date from HDFS when running a SHell Script on specific job?

Tags: bash, shell, apache-spark, hadoop

My task is to implement all the assigned tables for a particular Spark job.
I need to write a script based on the timestamp and path to be printed for all tables which are assigned to the job. I need to get all the timestamp associated with the tables associated with that job.

Here is my Script which I developed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
JOB_NAME=${1}
 inputDirListings=$(awk -F: -v key="$1" '$1==key {print $2}' test_paths.txt)
for dir in  $(echo $inputDirListings | tr "," "\n");
do
    path=$dir
    echo "dir is $path"
    cmd2='hdfs dfs -du -h $path'
    ev1=`eval $cmd2 | tail -1`
    echo "ev1 value is $ev1"

    hdfsPath=`echo $ev1 | cut -d";" -f3- `
    echo "partition is $hdfsPath"

    latestPartition=`echo $hdfsPath | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}'`
    echo "latest partition is $latestPartition"

    dt1="$(echo $ev1 | cut -d'=' -f2)"
    arr[i]=`date -d $dt1 +%Y%m%d`

    #---Getting minimum date from array---------
    max=${arr[0]}
    min=${arr[0]}

    for i in ${arr[@]}
    do
    if [[ $i > $max ]] ; then                           
    max=$i-1
    fi
    if [[ $i < $min ]] ; then
    min=$i
    fi
    echo "dt1"
    for (( c=$dt1; c<=$currDate; c++ ))
    do
        echo -n "$c "
        sleep 1
    done 
done
 echo "Max value is $max  , minimal value is $min"
dt2=`date -d $min +%Y-%m-%d`
done
```

I am getting an output as Max value and Min value as same value

eg: `Max size is 9999-12-31, Min size is 9999-12-31`

Basically, I need to get the latest partition date before `9999-12-31`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only stores the value of the partition in the last directory into the array, since it is overwritten each time in the loop.

Your array needs to be defined outside the loop, and `i` needs to be incremented within the loop, and you need to take your inner loop out, as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
JOB_NAME=${1}
arr=()
i=0

inputDirListings=$(awk -F: -v key="$1" '$1==key {print $2}' test_paths.txt)
for dir in  $(echo $inputDirListings | tr "," "\n");
do
    path=$dir
    echo "dir is $path"
    cmd2='hdfs dfs -du -h $path'
    ev1=`eval $cmd2 | tail -1`
    echo "ev1 value is $ev1"

    hdfsPath=`echo $ev1 | cut -d";" -f3- `
    echo "partition is $hdfsPath"

    latestPartition=`echo $hdfsPath | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}'`
    echo "latest partition is $latestPartition"

    dt1="$(echo $ev1 | cut -d'=' -f2)"
    arr[i]=`date -d $dt1 +%Y%m%d`

    let "i++"
echo "Max value is $max  , minimal value is $min"
dt2=`date -d $min +%Y-%m-%d`
done

#---Getting minimum date from array---------
max=${arr[0]}
min=${arr[0]}

for i in ${arr[@]}
do
    if [[ $i > $max ]] ; then                           
        max=$i-1
    fi
    if [[ $i < $min ]] ; then
        min=$i
    fi
    echo "dt1"
    for (( c=$dt1; c<=$currDate; c++ ))
    do
        echo -n "$c "
        sleep 1
    done 
done
```